# MissingManifestResourceException thrown when using OData query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I have an ASPNet Core Web API application that's utilizing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.vNext package. When using a query string to try to utilize OData functionality, I receive a MissingManifestResourceException. Here's the code in question:

```
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet()]
public class LocationsController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult GetLocations()
  {
    IQueryable<Location> locationEntities = _locationInfoRepo.GetLocations();
    if (locationEntities == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LocationDTO>>(locationEntities);

    return Ok(results);
  }
}
```

Note: I've already tried changing the type on the method from IActionResult to IQueryable<> to no avail. I've also commented out the Automapper Map method to ensure there were no issues there.

Here's the method that is utilizing EF to return the data:

```
public IQueryable<Location> GetLocations()
{
    return _context.Locations;
}
```

Here's the URL along with query string: http://localhost/api/locations?$filter=Name%20eq%20'Bob'

'Name' is a string field specified in the model, and is a column in the database.

Stack trace:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.SRResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.vNext" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
    at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
    at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.SRResources.GetString(String name, String[] formatterNames)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.SRResources.get_ClrTypeNotInModel()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.ODataQueryContext..ctor(IEdmModel model, Type elementClrType, ODataPath path)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<OnActionExecutionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To cross-reference the issue I've opened up with the OData team on the WebApi GitHub project, here's the link to that issue: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/955

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you have in your solution, but when I was having this issue I've solved just removing the [RouteAttribute] from my controller. Let me show you an working example.

In Startup.cs you should have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Your stuff...
    services.AddOData(opt => opt.RoutingConventions
                                    .Insert(0, new DefaultODataRoutingConvention()));
    // Your stuff...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Your stuff...
    var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IAssemblyProvider>();
    var model = GetEdmModel(provider);
    app.UseMvc(builder => builder
        .MapODataRoute("odata", model)
        .MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id?}"));
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IAssemblyProvider assemblyProvider)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(assemblyProvider);
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Then, in your controller you should have:

```
[EnableQuery]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{        
    private readonly IProductDbContext _dbContext;

    public ProductsController(IProductDbContext dbContext)
    {
         _dbContext = dbContext;
    }        

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Products.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

With the MapODataRoute the OData can find the ProductController whithout the need of any attribute or custom routing as you can look at [here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-01-routing-abstract).

So, there is no need of a RouteAttribute and this query "http://localhost:44302/odata/Products?$top=2&$skip=2" should work fine now.

Perhaps, you can post a more detailed code for us being able to help you. Hope you solved your problem.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'd decided since I ran into this issue, I'd moved to full .NET architecture, and moved on to full OData as well. It seems to be working well, but I'm a bit bummed that I wasn't able to get AspNetCore working appropriately. Maybe on my next project, I'll try this again with your solution. Thanks for the information!